# Display numeric and string type result in same cell of datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to display the result of MS access Query in DataGridView as below

```sql
Select clbal,Drcr from Ledger
```

Result in one DataGridView Cell As  2000Dr

I Have tried

```sql
Select cstr(clbal) & Drcr as cbal from Ledger
```

but no value is displayed in DataGridView cell

Comment: CStr() is not necessary for concatenating number and string fields. So something else is issue. Need to post code for setting up and populating DGV. Add tag for programming language.

Comment: How about you show us ALL the relevant code? If you execute a query and populate a `DataTable`, then bind that `DataTable` to the grid then the results of that query will be displayed. If it's not working for you then obviously you did something wrong, but if you don't show/tell us what you did then we can't help you fix it.

Comment: In this case the error is in the SQL query. Therefore, the code for setting up the DGV is not required.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you are quite much free to "concentate" field together, but some caution required if the "NEW" or created colum has the same name as existing columns. As a general rule, you should try and use a different column name.

So, say we have a FirstName column, and LastName column.

But, we want to display as full name.

And for just demonstration, we also was to have a FirstName + "id" as another column (this shows how a number PK can be combined with a string. As pointed out, you don't need (or in fact want to use cstr(), since that looks to be a VBA function anyway, and you can't use that in c#.

So, assuming a access table like this:

[image]

So, in above, the "ID" pk column is a number (long number in Access code/VBA
, int in c#)

So, we can in the query builder say write this:

[image]

So, when you make a expression in the SQL, give the column a name  (AS SomeFieldName).

Also, while Access SQL supports "&" or "+" for concatenation, one should probably get in the habit of using "+", and the reason is that the VAST majority of SQL data engines don't support using & for concatenation, but do support "+".

So, if I run above, then I get this:

[image]

Now, say c#, asp.net (or whatever platoform you using with c#),

The we have say this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table">
        </asp:GridView>
```

And our c# code to fill out the datatable (which then you can send to the above gridView, or your DataGridView.

The code will look like this:

```
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT ID, (FirstName + ' ' & LastName) AS FullName,
            (FirstName + '[' & ID & ']') AS FirstKey,
            HotelName, Description FROM tblHotelsA
            ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable rstData = MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();    // databind only need for web grid

    }

    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]